# Lift and frame matroids.

Tags: reference-request, lattice-orders, algebraic-graph-theory, matroids, algebraic-combinatorics

I want to read more about lift matroid and frame matroid and their flats and relations to signed graphs, do you know any basic resources for this?

Comment: Zaslavsky might have some papers on this from the 90s.

Comment: do you know the name of the papers please?@MathieuRundström